# How to set up a hash based director using vcl in Varnish which is using the hashed request body?

Tags: http, hash, varnish, vcl, varnish-vcl

I am trying to set up Varnish to route between backends using the request body's hash. I found good examples of using body access to set up caching where the hash of the request body is used as cache key. I cannot find an example of using the body hash for routing.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work. It is probably because bodyaccess was not meant to be used this way. How to set up a hash based director using vcl in Varnish which is using the hashed request body?

```
vcl 4.1;

import directors;
import bodyaccess;

backend backend1 {
    .host = "backend1.example.com";
    .port = "80";
}

backend backend2 {
    .host = "backend2.example.com";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_init {
    new xhash = directors.hash();
    xhash.add_backend(backend1);
    xhash.add_backend(backend2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = xhash.backend(bodyaccess.hash_req_body());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no real way to retrieve the request body as a string in Varnish Cache (open source). The `bodyaccess.hash_req_body()` function will actually add the request body to the caching hash in the `vcl_hash` subroutine. But since this function returns a *void* data type, this won't help you.

The only realistic way that I'm aware of is by using `vmod_xbody`, which is a Varnish Enterprise module. That module has an `xbody.get_req_body()` function that returns the request body as a string.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/xbody/#get-req-body for more information.